# Mapping to app root "/" is failing, but other than that is working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.2. I configured all things (not security, it is auto configured and need to convert all configuration from XML to Java. Authentication is working via LDAP) and working correctly **except** one thing i.e. mapping to `/` -> `redirect:/main`.

**Note:** This is a migration from Spring to Spring Boot with `.jsp` as view.

Below is the mapping in XML:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="redirect:/main" />
```

Above is working correctly in Spring but when converted to Spring Boot using Java code as below then **this specific case** is not working:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/main");
    }
}
```

**Note:** If I set `addViewController` something else like `/documentation` then it is redirecting successfully but not with `/`.

Comment: use `addRedirectViewController` instead of `addViewController`.

Comment: @M.Deinum No, it's not working.

Comment: Then you haven't done as adviced or have disabled stuff that you aren't showing.

Comment: I didn't understand by "haven't done as advised". For disable stuff, may be but for me I only disable Data source auto config. Also why other than / is working?

Comment: Again that should just work if it didn't you either didn't do it correctly (we don't know as you don't show) or you disabled parts of Spring (Boot) by trying too much yourself (again we don't know as you don't show). I also wonder what exactly isn't working... As you are using a JSP there are certain limitations and things you have to take into account when using Spring Boot (especially with embedded containers).

Answer (score 1):

you can use addRedirectViewController

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "redirect:/main");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things, finally got the solution. I need to `setOrder()` to highest precedence to work. But I still don't know why I need to do this for this specific case. Below is the code:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/main");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using addRedirectViewController() one have to set url name properly:

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "/yourURL");
}
```

- but NOT "redirect:/yourURL"